# How can I determine what program is listening on a port? It only listens for an instant. ss -tulpn is too slow

Tags: ubuntu

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 which, according to Wireshark, is sending an MQTT packet from port 38266 to a remote server every 30 seconds. I'm trying to determine what application is doing it. If I run `sudo ss -tulpn | grep :38266` I get no result. I'm guessing it only listens until it gets a response then disappears, which happens so quick I can't catch it. How can I figure out what application is sending the packet?

Comment: I think Wire Shark has a packet capture / logging capability. Set up a filter for your packets and then turn capture on.

Comment: There are a few already-answered questions on ServerFault about tracking down the source of short-lived network connections, e.g., https://serverfault.com/questions/352259/finding-short-lived-tcp-connections-owner-process

Comment: `tail -f | ss -tupln | grep :38266`, if it is too quick just ` > /tmp/ss.38266`